# Nginx URL rewriting - Prestashop

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, prestashop

I need to do a massive redirect in an online store.

The old URL has this format.

https://www.domain.com.br/web-cam/6046-webcam-com-microfone-usb-driverless--0000000006046.html

webcam-com-microfone-usb-driverless - product name
webcam is category
6046 is product ID
0000000006046.html is product EAN

The new format is more simple, like.

https://www.domain.com.br/webcam-com-microfone-usb-driverless-6046

Is possible to rewrite this?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with the following rewrite statement

```
rewrite ^/web-cam/([0-9]+)-(.*)--(.*).html$ /$2-$1 last;
```